# Is there a workaround to outdated VMWare certificate?

Tags: vmware

Last time I set up VMWare I did this workaround due to the outdated certificate. How can I make my installed client not care? It should work as I have done it before.

Klient version is 5.1.1. Does anyone know?

Comment: What kind of "certificate" are you talking about?

Comment: I really dont know. This is at work and the guy that knows takes his time. When I open the VMWare Viewer it states the the certificate is out of date. There is a workaround but I cant remember :/

Comment: You can generate a new certificate with OpenSSL or you can ask VMWare to [do it for you](http://myvirtualcloud.net/?p=811).